# API error (500): manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: openshift

it failes to pull the image with SHA256 digest identifier
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is a side-effect of DockerHub removing backwards compatibility for Docker 1.9 daemons.  When images are pushed using Docker 1.10, pull-by-id will fail for older daemons (which includes OpenShift masters importing metadata from the Hub).  You can work around this by pulling the centos image and pushing it to the internal registry.

At the current time, using Docker 1.9 on your hosts will avoid this issue.

Comment: Is there any way to work around this when you're pulling from automated builds onto a machine with Docker 1.9 (i.e. RHEL7?)

Comment: I just learned that Docker 1.10 is now available for Atomic Host as docker-latest!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a workaround for this issue by removing Image Change Trigger and removing the hash from `image` attribute in container spec.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the build config:

```
strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      from:
         kind: ImageStreamTag
         name: mysql-56-centos7
```

Replace to:

```
strategy:
   dockerStrategy:
      from:
         kind: DockerImage
         name: docker.io/centos/mysql-56-centos7:latest
```