# Importing Docker Images Images From The Public Registry Into OpenShift

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I am trying to deploy an Ubuntu Image from the [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jedisct1/phusion-baseimage-latest/) on OpenShift Online (Next Generation). These are the steps I followed in doing so

```
$ oc new-project test
$ oc new-app jedisct1/phusion-baseimage-latest

I then deployed from the WebConsole
```

However I get a failed deploy and an error status of "image pulled back off" on the pod page. Any particular thing that I may be doing wrong?

Below are the logs of the entire proccess.

```
root@home:~# oc new-project test
Now using project "test" on server "https://api.preview.openshift.com:443".

You can add applications to this project with the 'new-app' command. For example, try:

    $ oc new-app centos/ruby-22-centos7~https://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world.git

to build a new hello-world application in Ruby.

root@home:~# oc new-app jedisct1/phusion-baseimage-latest
--> Found Docker image 7ff0885 (14 hours old) from Docker Hub for "jedisct1/phusion-baseimage-latest"

    * An image stream will be created as "phusion-baseimage-latest:latest" that will track this image
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "phusion-baseimage-latest"
    * The image does not expose any ports - if you want to load balance or send traffic to this component
      you will need to create a service with 'expose dc/phusion-baseimage-latest --port=[port]' later
    * WARNING: Image "phusion-baseimage-latest" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator

--> Creating resources with label app=phusion-baseimage-latest ...
    imagestream "phusion-baseimage-latest" created
    deploymentconfig "phusion-baseimage-latest" created
--> Success
    Run 'oc status' to view your app.

root@home:~# oc status
In project test on server https://api.preview.openshift.com:443

dc/phusion-baseimage-latest deploys istag/phusion-baseimage-latest:latest
  deployment #1 pending on image or update

1 warning identified, use 'oc status -v' to see details.

root@home:~# oc status -v
In project test on server https://api.preview.openshift.com:443

dc/phusion-baseimage-latest deploys istag/phusion-baseimage-latest:latest
  deployment #1 pending on image or update

Warnings:
  * dc/phusion-baseimage-latest has no readiness probe to verify pods are ready to accept traffic or ensure deployment is successful.
    try: oc set probe dc/phusion-baseimage-latest --readiness ...

View details with 'oc describe <resource>/<name>' or list everything with 'oc get all'.

root@home:~# oc status -v
In project test on server https://api.preview.openshift.com:443

dc/phusion-baseimage-latest deploys istag/phusion-baseimage-latest:latest
  deployment #2 running for 2 minutes - 1 pod
```

Comment: are you able to do "docker pull jedisct1/phusion-baseimage-latest"?

Comment: No, not really. but I want to bypass anything to to with docker

Comment: Do you see manifest unknown in the events in your webconsole? I read about a 'bug' with pulling images which aren't build with version 1.9 or higher of docker (I'm able to pull the image on docker)

Comment: Yes, I was just asking, because if you can't pull the image with docker command on the same host running openshift, that means that neither openshift will be able to pull it. Do you have any proxy configuration?

Comment: Just to clarify things this is OpenShift Online (Next Generation)

Comment: Yes OpenShift pulls the image successfully. And a digest (pull spec) is shown on the WebConsole. I then try to deploy it but it simply fails due to a time-out. I have tried deploying four times all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. using Docker < 1.10 pull the image

2. tag it either as

     docker.io/<yourname>/imagename

     or

     ${INTERNAL_DOCKER_REGISTRY_IP}/openshift/imagename

3. push it using the same tag

4. deploy from that
```

Using docker < 1.10, you may be sure that the pushed image will be of schema v1 which is importable both by current registry version and docker 1.9.

Pulling images is no problem, because Docker hub converts it on the fly to schema v1 which has a different digest than the one on the hub. So if you try to pull using this digest you will fail because it isn't stored on the hub. Thus the deployer will fail because docker fails to pull given digest.

Basically, you can push it anywhere as long as you use docker < 1.10 so you can be sure that the resulting image manifest will be of schema v1 - such a manifest can be safely consumed by the OpenShift and docker of any version.

*Alternative Approach*

You can also push it to OpenShift Online with any docker version you want. Because OpenShift's registry stores only v1 schema. Then refer to the pushed image instead of original source on the Docker Hub.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to pull the same image in Openshift online too, and I found out a "manifest unknow error".

[image]

This is a compatibility problem with DockerHub, as Clayton states in this answer.

[API error (500): manifest unknown: manifest unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709594/api-error-500-manifest-unknown-manifest-unknown)

Comment: have you pulled any other ubuntu image in successfully?