# ImagePullBackOff after deploy to OpenShift

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

I'm starting with Docker and OpenShift v3.

I have a simple Node.js project and a Dockerfile basically copied from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) that runs perfectly fine on my local machine with `docker run`. I pushed my image to Docker Hub and then created my project via `oc new-project`.

After `oc new-app` and `oc get pods`, I see a pod with status `ImagePullBackOff` and another as `Running`. After sometime, only one pod lasts, with status `Error`. `oc logs` only brings me: `pods for deployment took longer than 600 seconds to become ready`.

Another thing that probably could help is that, after the `oc new-app` command, I got a message like `* [WARNING] Image runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator`.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Is more info needed?

You can see my Docker file in [here](http://pastebin.com/RXwD3MGX) and my project's code in [here](https://github.com/nhanderu/personal).

Answer (score 0):

By default OpenShift will prevent you from running containers as root due to the security risk. Whether you can configure a cluster to allow you to run a specific container as root will depend on what privileges you have to administer the cluster.

You are better off not running your container as root in the first place. To do that suggest you use the image at:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/ryanj/centos7-s2i-nodejs/

This image is Source-to-Image (S2I) enabled and so integrates with OpenShift's build system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my delay. The `Image runs as the 'root' user` message disappeared, but the main problem remains.

Comment: Are you now using the node.js images from Ryan? Are there any messages showing in the events tab in the OpenShift web interface (main events tab, not pod/deployment ones)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457982/importing-docker-images-images-from-the-public-registry-into-openshift

Comment: @MohammedSohail If using Ryan's image, that Docker version issue mentioned in link shouldn't apply as believe Ryan's image uses older Docker version. Thus why trying to clarify what was image was being used now after had been already suggested that should use Ryan's image to eliminate root warning.